# How to disable "Access can be package-private" message in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Developing an API, the warning message "Access can be package-package" in Java classes can be really annoying.

I've already spent some time going through the settings to find a way to disable this message but without any findings. Any idea how to disable the message?

Comment: Mine is telling me a method can be package-private, but when I do so, the other places in my code where it's being called won't work (as you'd expect), so why is it telling me it can be package-private? It can't be if I'm using it elsewhere. Not a very helpful suggestion from the IDE here.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The inspection rule is "Declaration access can be weaker" and there are two options which can be disabled "Suggest package-private visibility level..."

Answer (score 71):

Go to `Settings → Editor → Inspections` then `Java → Declaration redundancy → Declaration access can be weaker` rule.
Here you can either disable it at all or select the suggestion options on the right pane:

[image]

Answer (score 61):

To disable on a case by case basis, use

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
```

Comment: This is the best answer. By doing this you actually document your intention, instead of having the IDE blanket-cover everything for you

Comment: I'd have said declaring a method as public already documented your intention. But I get the point. If you say it twice, then they'll start believing that you really mean it.

Comment: It's actually an old anti-pattern to make everything private. TDD users will understand this better than anyone. Essentially, unless you are writing code for distribution and need to protect the internals from you users, making everything private, makes testing and refactoring more difficult. With that in mind, Mayne its not such a bad idea to make it IDE wide.

Comment: Even then, I'm pretty sure you can configure some obfuscators to change access for you.

Comment: @BrillPappin Do you have any source that I can read about the idea that keeping everything at the weakest access possible (not "make everything private", which I'm sure nobody has ever advocated) is an anti-pattern? And makes refactoring more difficult? In my view making everything public will gradually turn the code into a bowl of spaghetti where everything depends on everything.

Comment: You definitely don't want a bowl of spaghetti :) I misspoke, I should have said it's a code smell, not an antipattern, although you could make that statement as well, when you start understanding why it's a smell. If you are practicing a discipline like TDD (and especially don't use mocking), then it becomes apparent immediately. 
...

Comment: ...
In fact, I'd say that the unit tests are significantly more important, than writing your code in a way that *protects it from yourself*. Unless this is an API meant for distribution, then the code is already private, so why are you creating a bowl of spaghetti for yourself? I'm not saying that you should never have a private method, far from it, but the idea that everything should automatically be private is absurd. You are just creating a black box. 
...

Comment: ...
Anyway, this discussion goes back at least 20 years, I'm not positive, but I think I first read it in print in Kent Beck's book on TDD. Here are a couple of links to get you started: http://wiki.c2.com/?CodeSmell http://wiki.c2.com/?MethodsShouldBePublic I found a few good arguments from the other side as well: http://carlosschults.net/en/are-private-methods-a-code-smell/ From experience, I can tell you I've run across more trouble from overly privatized code than anything else, because it starts looking like your bowl of spaghetti internally, where no test can adequately reach.

Answer (score 8):

Move the cursor to `public` , press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose one of the options:
[image]

Comment: Interestingly I don't have the option "Disable inspection" when selecting "Make 'package-private'". (Probably I've disabled another setting so that I don't see that option.) I'm sure your answer works. Thank you. mboss' solution did the trick for me.

Comment: Worked for me :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this disable *all* "Declaration access can be weaker" suggestions, not just the ones suggesting package-private?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution not mentioned so far: if you have a method that's declared public, and the IDE is telling you that there are no references to the method from outside the package, then perhaps you need to add a test case that calls that method from outside the package. In other words, treat the warning as signalling the absence of a test case for a public method.

Comment: Since it is common that the testing class is in the same package as the class under test, this will not really change anything.

Comment: @Stefan: Typically unit tests sit in the same package, but a public API should be tested in e.g. integration or acceptance tests and should use the public API as a true client would do. From outside, I think.