# "Access can be private" warning message for public setter/mutator methods in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I have a public class with private fields and public setter methods to set those fields. Why IntelliJ IDEA is warning me saying "Access can be private" for these setter methods?

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code to demonstrate what you mean? The class in question and where it's used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: because IntelliJ doesn't see any usages for these method that would require them to be `public` in your project.

In other words: the IDE doesn't "know" that you made the setters `public` on purpose. It just figured: for what you are doing right now, you don't have to do that.

When writing "truly" public APIs, (maybe to be used by 3rd parties that *later* rely on your classes), this information is safe to ignore. So you might just go in and disable that warning, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716196/how-to-disable-access-can-be-package-package-message-in-intellij-2016/41716317) for example.

Beyond that: understand that you should avoid public setters where possible. Unless you have a "data bean" class, having setters/getters for each and any field is actually **bad** practice. You avoid outsiders to inspect internal state (using getters), and you very much want to prevent outsiders to overwrite internal state (using setters).

Comment: These are used outside from the class. Updated question.

Comment: @Saikat Then IntelliJ wouldn't warn like that. If they really could be private, then you aren't using them "publicly". Or it is an IntelliJ bug.

Comment: My bad, just noticed the setter is called in the same class.

Comment: Which underlines my point from the update: be really careful about having setters in the first place ;-)

Comment: what kind of a dumb solution is this though? Why isn't there a way to disable this on specified fields?

Comment: @Enerccio Again, this is about fighting symptoms. You shouldnt have unused public methods. That simple. In the end, there should be at least one unit test calling it, right?!

Comment: @GhostCat, except that on my IDEA rev (2021.3 CE), that inspection is currently flagging the public *constructors*.  That's just silly.  I can disable the inspection for the method, but 1. I don't think that's IDE-independent enough and 2. Gross.

Answer (score 1):

It means they are not used outside of the class and don't need to be public.

Restricting the access of methods keeps your interfaces small and reduces the chance of bugs creeping into your programs.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA is intelligent enough to scan your packages and class references within a package and if it notices that the usage is enclosed primarily to a certain package, then it will try to instill some discipline of adherence to encapsulation principles, and in this case: package privateness.
 If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes.